# How to repair user directory on Ubuntu server 20.04

Tags: ubuntu

For a project I have two servers, staging and production. The project is very old and I had not upgraded the OS from Ubuntu 14.04. As upgrading was out of question, recently I migrated the production server to a new VPS with Ubuntu 20.04.2. I am not sure where I went wrong, but these are now the symptoms:

**Worong Promot**
Whenever I SSH into the server as root all is normal, but when I switch to the normal user with `su appuser` the prompt becomes a bare `$`, no username, no host name and no path in the prompt.

**No auto-completion**
Also, I am unable to autocomplete paths in commands. I.e. when I type `/ho` and hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>, instead of the line becoming `/home` a literal tab character is added like `/ho`    .

**No command history**
When I hit the <kbd>UP</kbd> key, instead of getting the last executed command, the line becomes `$ ^[[A`.

**Cron jobs not executed**
I have several cronjobs and I am sure there is no issue with the defining line or the service they call as they worked in the old production server and still work in the staging server. The jobs are not executed at all on the new server.

**Missing files**
I compared the list of files on the staging server and the new production server and noticed a number of files are missing in the new server. For example, there was no `.bashrc` file in the new servers's `/home/appuser` directory. I added the file manually but nothing changed. So I thought I should seek help.

How can I repair the `appuser`?

Comment: Looks like user creation went wrong. Usually the contents of `/etc/skel` would be copied to new user accounts. Try doing that manually, fix the file permissions if applicable, and then re-login the `appuser` account.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you check that the home folder and the default shell are set for that user in `/etc/passwd` ?

Comment: @GabrielNúñezYuvé Good catch! In /etc/passwd I have this line for appuser: `appuser:x:1000:1000::/home/appuser:/bin/sh` which interestingly is different from that of root which is: `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash` so I have an empty token after group ID and `sh` in place of `bash`. I had compared the home directory with `/etc/skel` as recommended by Mikael but found no missing files. Please add an answer and advise if it is wise to edit the `/etc/passwd` with nano, or if it should be done with a different tool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default shell looks like it's a "minimal" shell. If you wish the *appuser* to have the same shell as *root* you should change the default shell to `/bin/bash`.
You can do this by editing the `/etc/passwd` file and replace the `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` using your preferred text editor (such as `vi`, `vim` or `nano`), or the other option is using the `chsh` command, like:

```sh
chsh appuser -s /bin/bash
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I used `vipw` instead of using nano directly and after adding a name token and changing `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`, as you had hinted, all symptoms were fixed. Thank you! Using `vipw` was something I learned about in this article titled *The Right Way To Edit /etc/passwd And /etc/group Files In Linux* - link: https://web.archive.org/web/20210331085207/https://ostechnix.com/the-right-way-to-edit-etc-passwd-and-etc-group-files-in-linux/